# Javascript form: call a specified submit button when a select field changes value

Tags: javascript, submit, onchange

I have a form with multiple submit buttons, one of which is a reload button that's proving hard to code.

The idea is that when the user clicks "reload", the form is submitted, and it's updated based on the value of a select field. The code snippet for that bit is simple (cut down to basics):

```
<select type="text" id="dataamount" size="1">
    <option value="time0h10m">Latest 10 minutes</option>
    <option value="time1h00m">Latest 1 hour</option>
    <option value="time12h00m">Latest 12 hours</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="btnreload" value="reload latest data">
<input type="submit" id="btndelete" value="delete all">
<input type="submit" id="btnrun" value="run">
```

Then I thought, if the user changes the "reload" field value, that should trigger submitting via the "reload" button anyway. (Why force them to change and *then* click, = 2 actions? Far nicer to trigger the submit automatically when dataamount -> onchange occurs.) But I'd have to specify which submit button, not just submit the form. That's the problem.

I wanted to do something like this, but I gather this won't work or isn't reliable:

```
<select type="text" id="dataamount" size="1" 
         onchange="document.getElementById('btnreload').submit();">
etc

or              "..... ('btnreload').click();
```

but I can't find any guide to do this, or giving the options I have. There are occasional hints that click() of a submit field may be poorly supported or submit fields can't always be executed using .submit().

I'm after good compatibility and using pure javascript (no jquery etc). Ideally I'd like to keep it inline and avoid (enable/disable + form.submit()) workarounds if possible (submit buttons could change or become dynamic).

Comment: Use buttons `tpye=button` or you'd have to `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` on all those submit buttons...

Comment: Because one of them will "randomly" trigger if the user presses Enter??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to give your `select` and `input` elements `name` attributes for any data to be submitted to server.

Second, add a hidden input to the form and in `select` `onchange` event set its value to something you can check for in server-side code and then submit the form:

```
document.getElementById("hiddenInputId").value = "dataAmountChanged";
document.forms[0].submit();
```

Comment: Meaning it gives rise to 2 possibilities on submission: (a) the hidden field is null, then submission must have been by the user clicking a button, and (b) it's set, then submission must have been via a change of that field prior to submission [and so whichever submit button it's saying was clicked, ignore it]? That makes very good sense.

Comment: Almost. If the hidden field value is present, then form submission was caused by `document.forms[0].submit();` and not by the button click - the value of a submit button will not even be in the submitted data.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<select type="text" id="dataamount" size="1" 
         onchange="myFunction();">

 function myFunction() {
        document.querySelectorAll("input[type=submit]")[0].click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
 document.querySelectorAll("input[type=submit]")[0].click();
```